# question on pgfplots and pos=

Tags: pgfplots

In pgfplots, pos=a , with a between 0 and 1, refers to the relative x coordinate on a plot. I was wondering if there is an equivalent construct that accept the absolute x coordinate rather than the relative value?

Comment: what your `pos=` used for?If it is for some mark in your figure, you could use this `\addplot[sharp plot] coordinates {(4E-6,0) (4E-6,15)};` to plot vertical line.

Comment: if you want absolute position, how about using a `node` with `axis cs`?

Comment: @cmhughes : I need to have a point on the plot at, say, x=3 by using axis cs I need to first compute the y coordinate of this point. I would like to skip this computation if possible (this is a comment, but the "add comment" link did not work).

Comment: You have apparently created two accounts, and because this second account has less than 50 rep you can't comment on the post of your first account. Follow the instructions here to have them merged: http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: What you want is a good idea, and I believe that @Jake as a couple of answers with related solitions on this site. However, `pgfplots` only supports relative positions up to now.